# SparseLU Eigen issus

Tags: c++, eigen

I am testing a simple `Eigen::SparseLU` routine. I'm receiving a warning that I don't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "EigenLibrary/Eigen/Dense"
#include "EigenLibrary/Eigen/Sparse"
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    VectorXd X(3),b(3);
    b.setRandom();
    SparseMatrix<double> A(3,3);
    A.setIdentity();
    SparseLU<SparseMatrix<double>, COLAMDOrdering<int>> lu;
    lu.analyzePattern(A);
    lu.factorize(A);
    X = lu.solve(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is placement

```
placement new constructing an object of type ‘Eigen::RefBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > >::Base’ {aka ‘Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >, 1>’} and size ‘24’ in a region of type ‘Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >, 1>’ and size ‘17’ [-Wplacement-new=]
```

Can someone hep me please.

Comment: Could you add the compilation options you are using? Did you explicitly add `-Wplacement-new` and perhaps `-Werror`? Also what compiler/version do you use?

Comment: this code very similar to the example from the eigen docs: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html

Comment: i' m using g++ -std=c++11  -o run testlu.cpp to compile the code.

Comment: The error is not reproducible https://godbolt.org/z/7WfG6oWWK . It either occurs elsewhere in your code, or there is something wrong with your Eigen installation or compiler version.